# Morphological analysis of 'unlawfulness'

Tags: word-usage, word-form

How would you give the internal structure of the word 'unlawfulness'? 

My attempt:
un - law - ful - ness
prefix - noun - suffix - suffix

Internal structure:
law + ful > Adjective
un + law + ful > Adjective
un + law + ful + ness > Noun

Will that be correct? Should I split 'lawful' into 'law + ful' so there's four morphemes in the word or keep it as three morphemes? If 'lawful' is split, then is the -ful counted as a suffix or an infix?

Comment: *ful* is a distinct morpheme. Sorrowful. Mournful. Joyful.

Comment: -ful turns the noun into an adjective and -ness turns that adjective into an abstract noun.  -un, of course, is "not". The-behavior-that-lacks-the-characteristic-of-being-within-the-law.

Comment: You can complete the breakdown by adding the Adverb form.
un·lawful·ly adv.
un·lawful·ness n.
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unlawfulness

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have it right.  There are four morphemes, of which the outer three are affixes:

> [ *un-* [ ***law*** *-ful* ] ] *-ness*
>
> [image: morphology tree]

In order, the affixes are ① the **suffix** [*-ful*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/-ful), ② the **prefix** [*un-*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/un-), and ③ the **suffix** [*-ness*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/-ness).

There are no infixes here.

Answer (score 0):

There are four morphemes. *Law* is the only free morpheme of the group; *-ful* (*lawful*) is a suffix, *un-* (*unlawful*) is a prefix, *-ness* (*unlawfulness*) is a suffix.

This is true even though *lawful* does not mean exactly what one might expect from *law* and *-ful*.